# Можно ли собственное и нарицательное назвать признаком существительного?

Tags: грамматика, существительные

Является ли постоянным лексико-грамматическим признаком имени существительного его отнесение к имени собственному или имени нарицательному?

Answer (score 2):

См. [**[Е. И. Литневская. Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников]**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part4#i2):

> **Морфологический разбор существительного**
>
> Существительное разбирается по следующей схеме:
>
> 1. Начальная форма.
> 2. Морфологические признаки:
>
> **а) постоянные:**
>
> **— собственное / нарицательное,**
>
> — конкретное / абстрактное / вещественное / собирательное,
>
> — род,
>
> — число (для тех существительных, для которых этот признак
>   постоянный),
>
> — одушевленность,
>
> — склонение;
>
> б) непостоянные:
>
> — число (для изменяющихся по числам),
>
> — падеж.
>
> 3. Синтаксическая роль в предложении.